# How to get Spring Cloud Config dependencies to resolve from parent configuration in Gradle multi-module build?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-cloud-config

In an effort to put together an example project for Spring Cloud Config server and (Java and non-Java) clients using Vault, I decided to go the route of a multi-module Gradle build. Since I already had two working Java projects (server and client), I figured that I could pull the common configuration up into the parent `build.gradle` and conditionally apply the configuration for the Java subprojects. I started with the server subproject, and ran into an issue that I've been unable to resolve.

The `build.gradle` for the parent module looks like:

```
plugins {
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.0.RELEASE' apply false
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE' apply false
  id 'idea'
}

ext {
   set('springCloudVersion', "Hoxton.SR4")
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

  version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}


subprojects {
  // We'll need dependencies for Docker and Docker compose

  afterEvaluate { project ->
    if (project.usesSpringBoot) {
      println("Configuring ${springCloudVersion}")
      configure(project) {
        apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
        apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
        apply plugin: 'java'

        group = 'com.daecabhir'
        sourceCompatibility = '11'

        dependencies {
          implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
          implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
          implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config'
          developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
          testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
            exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
          }
        }

        dependencyManagement {
          imports {
            mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
          }
        }

        test {
          useJUnitPlatform()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the `build.gradle` for the `cloud-config-server` subproject looks like:

```
ext {
  usesSpringBoot = true
}
```

Unfortunately attempting a `./gradlew build` leaves me with an error that it cannot find a class from Spring Cloud Config:

```
/home/gwright/projects/cloud-config-vault-example/cloud-config-server/src/main/java/com/daecabhir/cloudconfigserver/CloudConfigServerApplication.java:5: error: package org.springframework.cloud.config.server does not exist
import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnableConfigServer;
                                              ^
/home/gwright/projects/cloud-config-vault-example/cloud-config-server/src/main/java/com/daecabhir/cloudconfigserver/CloudConfigServerApplication.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
@EnableConfigServer
 ^
  symbol: class EnableConfigServer
2 errors
```

When I check the dependencies, I get the following for compile time:

```
compileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator -> 2.3.0.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.3.0.RELEASE
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.0 (c)
|    |    +--- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:1.5.1 (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.2.6.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.2.6.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:2.3.0.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.3.0.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.3.0.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:2.3.0.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:2.3.0.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.3.0.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.3.0.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.3.0.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:2.3.0.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:1.3.5 (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.6.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.26 (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:2.3.0.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.11.0 (c)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.11.0 (c)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:2.11.0 (c)
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:9.0.35 (c)
|    |    +--- org.glassfish:jakarta.el:3.0.3 (c)
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:9.0.35 (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.6.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.2.6.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.2.6.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.2.6.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.11.0 (c)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.0 (c)
|    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3 (c)
|    |    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.13.2 (c)
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.30 (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.2.6.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:5.3.2.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3 (c)
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30 (c)
|    |    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.13.2 (c)
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.3.0.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.3.0.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.3.0.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.3.0.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core -> 5.2.6.RELEASE
|    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.2.6.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context -> 5.2.6.RELEASE
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.2.6.RELEASE
|    |    |         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.6.RELEASE
|    |    |         |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.2.6.RELEASE
|    |    |              \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.3.0.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.3.0.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.3.0.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:2.3.0.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.3.0.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic -> 1.2.3
|    |    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.30
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j -> 2.13.2
|    |    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.30
|    |    |    |    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.13.2
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j -> 1.7.30
|    |    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
|    |    +--- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api -> 1.3.5
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core -> 5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.yaml:snakeyaml -> 1.26
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:2.3.0.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.3.0.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:2.3.0.RELEASE
|    |         \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.3.0.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- io.micrometer:micrometer-core -> 1.5.1
|         \--- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:2.1.12
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web -> 2.3.0.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.3.0.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.3.0.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:2.3.0.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.3.0.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.3.0.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-web -> 5.2.6.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind -> 2.11.0
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.11.0
|    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.0
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8 -> 2.11.0
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.0
|    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310 -> 2.11.0
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.11.0
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.0
|    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names -> 2.11.0
|    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.0
|    |         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.0 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:2.3.0.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.3.0.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api -> 1.3.5
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core -> 9.0.35
|    |    +--- org.glassfish:jakarta.el -> 3.0.3
|    |    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket -> 9.0.35
|    |         \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:9.0.35
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-web -> 5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc -> 5.2.6.RELEASE
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
\--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config -> 2.2.2.RELEASE
     +--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:2.2.2.RELEASE
     |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.2.5.RELEASE -> 2.3.0.RELEASE (*)
     |    +--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:2.2.2.RELEASE
     |    |    \--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:5.2.2.RELEASE -> 5.3.2.RELEASE
     |    +--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:2.2.2.RELEASE
     |    |    \--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:5.2.2.RELEASE -> 5.3.2.RELEASE
     |    \--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsa:1.0.9.RELEASE
     |         \--- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.64
     |              \--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.64
     +--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-client:2.2.2.RELEASE
     |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.2.5.RELEASE -> 2.3.0.RELEASE (*)
     |    +--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:2.2.2.RELEASE (*)
     |    +--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:2.2.2.RELEASE (*)
     |    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.2.4.RELEASE -> 5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
     |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.2 -> 2.11.0
     |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.2 -> 2.11.0 (*)
     \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.2 -> 2.11.0 (*)
```

which on the face of it looks reasonable, except that it isn't. It seems that Gradle is honoring the dependencies, but they are not getting fully resolved by dependency management. When I fall back to fully specifying the configuration in the `cloud-config-server` subproject using the following parent `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.0.RELEASE' apply false
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE' apply false
  id 'idea'
}

ext {
   set('springCloudVersion', "Hoxton.SR4")
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

  version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

and a subproject `build.gradle` of:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.daecabhir'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-server'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

the build works fine, and the dependencies are more fully "resolved" (the spring-cloud-config-server dependency in particular):

```
compileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web -> 2.3.0.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.3.0.RELEASE
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.11.0 (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.2.6.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.2.6.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:5.3.2.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.3.0.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.3.0.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:2.3.0.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:2.3.0.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:2.3.0.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.3.0.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.26 (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.3.0.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.3.0.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:2.3.0.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:1.3.5 (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.6.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.0 (c)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.11.0 (c)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.11.0 (c)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:2.11.0 (c)
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:9.0.35 (c)
|    |    +--- org.glassfish:jakarta.el:3.0.3 (c)
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:9.0.35 (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.6.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.2.6.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.2.6.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.2.6.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.11.0 (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:2.3.0.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:1.5.1 (c)
|    |    +--- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:6.1.5.Final (c)
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30 (c)
|    |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.12 (c)
|    |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.13 (c)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.0 (c)
|    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3 (c)
|    |    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.13.2 (c)
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.30 (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.2.6.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:2.3.0.RELEASE (c)
|    |    +--- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:2.0.2 (c)
|    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.4.1.Final (c)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.5.1 (c)
|    |    +--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.14 (c)
|    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3 (c)
|    |    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.13.2 (c)
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.3.0.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.3.0.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.3.0.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.3.0.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core -> 5.2.6.RELEASE
|    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.2.6.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context -> 5.2.6.RELEASE
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.2.6.RELEASE
|    |    |         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.6.RELEASE
|    |    |         |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.2.6.RELEASE
|    |    |              \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.3.0.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.3.0.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.3.0.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:2.3.0.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.3.0.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic -> 1.2.3
|    |    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.30
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j -> 2.13.2
|    |    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.30
|    |    |    |    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.13.2
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j -> 1.7.30
|    |    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
|    |    +--- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api -> 1.3.5
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core -> 5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.yaml:snakeyaml -> 1.26
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:2.3.0.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.3.0.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.3.0.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-web -> 5.2.6.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind -> 2.11.0
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.11.0
|    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.0
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8 -> 2.11.0
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.0
|    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310 -> 2.11.0
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.11.0
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.0
|    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names -> 2.11.0
|    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.0
|    |         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.0 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:2.3.0.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.3.0.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api -> 1.3.5
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core -> 9.0.35
|    |    +--- org.glassfish:jakarta.el -> 3.0.3
|    |    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket -> 9.0.35
|    |         \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:9.0.35
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-web -> 5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc -> 5.2.6.RELEASE
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
\--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-server -> 2.2.2.RELEASE
     +--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-client:2.2.2.RELEASE
     |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.2.5.RELEASE -> 2.3.0.RELEASE (*)
     |    +--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:2.2.2.RELEASE
     |    |    \--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:5.2.2.RELEASE -> 5.3.2.RELEASE
     |    +--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:2.2.2.RELEASE
     |    |    \--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:5.2.2.RELEASE -> 5.3.2.RELEASE
     |    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.2.4.RELEASE -> 5.2.6.RELEASE (*)
     |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.2 -> 2.11.0
     |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.2 -> 2.11.0 (*)
     +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.2.5.RELEASE -> 2.3.0.RELEASE
     |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.3.0.RELEASE (*)
     |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.3.0.RELEASE (*)
     |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:2.3.0.RELEASE
     |    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.3.0.RELEASE (*)
     |    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:2.3.0.RELEASE
     |    |         \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.3.0.RELEASE (*)
     |    \--- io.micrometer:micrometer-core -> 1.5.1
     |         \--- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:2.1.12
     +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.2.5.RELEASE -> 2.3.0.RELEASE (*)
     +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:2.2.5.RELEASE -> 2.3.0.RELEASE
     |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.3.0.RELEASE (*)
     |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.3.0.RELEASE (*)
     |    +--- org.glassfish:jakarta.el -> 3.0.3
     |    \--- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator -> 6.1.5.Final
     |         +--- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:2.0.2
     |         +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.2.Final -> 3.4.1.Final
     |         \--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.3.4 -> 1.5.1
     +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:5.2.2.RELEASE -> 5.3.2.RELEASE
     +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsa:1.0.9.RELEASE
     |    \--- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.64
     |         \--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.64
     +--- org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:5.1.3.201810200350-r
     |    +--- com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.54
     |    +--- com.jcraft:jzlib:1.1.1
     |    +--- com.googlecode.javaewah:JavaEWAH:1.1.6
     |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.2 -> 1.7.30
     +--- org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit.http.apache:5.1.3.201810200350-r
     |    +--- org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:5.1.3.201810200350-r (*)
     |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.5 -> 4.5.12
     |    |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.13
     |    |    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.11 -> 1.14
     |    \--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.9 -> 4.4.13
     +--- org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.25 -> 1.26
     \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.10.2 -> 2.11.0
          +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.0 (*)
          +--- org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.26
          \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.0
```

So my question is, what do I need to do in order to be able to specify the configuration in the parent project selectively based on a property so that the dependencies will be fully resolved? And what is it about how I specified the configuration that is causing it to not fully resolve the dependencies?

FWIW, the full code for the project can be found here:

- Using parent configuration, not working: https://github.com/daecabhir/cloud-config-vault-example/tree/feat/multi-module-java-builds
- Using explicit subproject configuration, working: https://github.com/daecabhir/cloud-config-vault-example/tree/feat/multi-module-java-build-working

Comment: For clarification, `cloud-config-client` and `cloud-config-server` should be part of the _same_ multi-project build?

Comment: Ultimately,  yes. Right now only `cloud-config-server` is included via `settings.gradle`. I sho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made a PR to your repo: https://github.com/daecabhir/cloud-config-vault-example/pull/3

---

Rather than using a property to control if a project is a Spring Boot project (didn't work for me), you can define a list of projects that are Spring Boot based projects, then apply defaults which you have done.

```
plugins {
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.0.RELEASE' apply false
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE' apply false
  id 'idea'
}

ext {
   set('springCloudVersion', "Hoxton.SR4")
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

  version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

// List of Spring Boot based projects
def springBootProjects = [
  project(":cloud-config-server"),
  project(":cloud-config-client")
]
```

Once you have your list, then simply iterate over them, applying based configuration to them:

```
springBootProjects.each { springBootProject ->
  configure(springBootProject) {
    println("Configuring $name as a Spring Boot project")

    apply {
      plugin("org.springframework.boot")
      plugin("io.spring.dependency-management")
      plugin("java")
    }

    group = "com.daecabhir"
    sourceCompatibility = "11"

    dependencies {
      implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
      implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
      developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
      testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
      }
    }

    dependencyManagement {
      imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
      }
    }

    tasks {
      test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You had `spring-cloud-starter-config` as an import for the server application, but that is incorrect because the `spring-cloud-starter-config` module brings in `spring-cloud-config-client` which is not what is needed for a config server as it leads to import issues.

So rather than defining the dependency there as a base dependency, move it to the project itself:

`cloud-config-server/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
  implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-server"
}
```

`cloud-config-client/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
  implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config"
}
```

With these changes, the resulting output is:

```
$ ./gradlew assemble

> Configure project :
Configuring cloud-config-server as a Spring Boot project
Configuring cloud-config-client as a Spring Boot project

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
6 actionable tasks: 6 up-to-date
```

Comment: I will take a look at this when I get home this evening. The strange things are (a) the use of `spring-cloud-starter-config` I thought came from using Spring Initializr to generate the server project (which I will check), and (b) it worked fine in the standalone project as defined. Not doubting you, just passing strange.

Comment: That appears to work, and I am going to have to assume that when I was working with Spring Initializr that I selected the Config Client and not the Config Server dependency. Thank you for your help.

Comment: spring-cloud-starter-config version should be set manually, i don't know why but it doesn't took any version from parent...